# Can I perform complex queries using Parse? (parse.com)

Tags: android, parse-platform, nosql

I come from a relational database platform (Oracle) and from my understanding parse is a NoSQL database.
Is it possible to perform complex queries such as join between two or more tables, sum/groupby etc? (RDBMS stuff)

If it is possible I'd be happy to get some example from you.

I'm using parse for Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the NoSQL database provide built in functionality like couchdb offers SUM, COUNT and Stats.

Check out the link. https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions.

To perform these queries in Oracle Nosql, you need to write logic in java. These have some limitation like If you use Key/Value ApI and JSON format, you will not be able to these. May be these are possible in TableApI Using java.

Answer (score 1):

Parse is great for simple apps.   However,  you have to write logic to construct a query in thr app.   Incredibly difficult,  time consuming and error prone.    I'm a big fan of parse,  but I avoid it for anything complex